# Draw only regions of a hyperboloid in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm interested in the hyperboloid `u^2 + v^2 - w^2 = 1`, which can be parameterized as

```
u = cosh(x) cos(y),
v = cosh(x) sin(y),
w = sinh(x).
```

This parameterization can be used to draw the hyperboloid in pgfplots as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[surf,
            fill=white,
            samples=10,
            samples y=72,
            domain=-1:1,
            y domain=0:360,
            z buffer=sort]
            ( {cosh(x)*cos(y)}, {cosh(x)*sin(y)}, {sinh(x)} );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That works beautifully, but now I would like to restrict the plot to, say, the region where `v + w > 0`. In terms of my `(x,y)` parameters this reads `cosh(x) sin(y) + sinh(x) > 0`. According to the PGFPlots manual I should be able to use the `restrict expr to domain` option to accomplish this, but when I try it I get a LaTeX error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''..
```

I'm assuming this option should be given at the `\addplot3` level, not at the `\begin{axis}` level, but the error appears either way.

Actually what I would like to do is plot the hyperboloid twice; first, the full hyperboloid in a nice subdued gray, and then, on top of it, the region of interest in bright colors, so that it can actually be identified as part of the hyperboloid.

---

I'm providing an updated MWE since I guess the whole thing got a bit confusing with all the changing in variable names. Here's what I intended to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[view={120}{5},
              samples=20,
              samples y=72,
              domain=-2:2,
              y domain=0:360,
              z buffer=sort,
              variable=\u,
              variable y=\v]
  \addplot3[surf,
            restrict expr to domain={y+z}{0:100}]
            ( {cosh(u)*cos(v)}, {cosh(u)*sin(v)}, {sinh(u)} );
 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With the unstable version of pgfplots installed, this draws only half of the hyperboloid---the half determined by the condition `y + z > 0`---, as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in the current stable pgfplots 1.7 (sorry).

I have fixed it in the pgfplots unstable (available at http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/).

Note that your example suffers from a usability issue in pgfplots: as soon as pgfplots has evaluated the parametric coordinates, it redefines `x` to be the *resulting* X coordinate and `y` to be the resulting Y coordinate. Thus, your example works if you switch to `variable=u, variable y=w`. Of course, you could also employ the usability issue and write `restrict expr to domain={y + z}{0:99999}`.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure as to what you mean by a "usability issue". Does it mean it is somehow more "efficient" for pgfplots if the parameters are called, e.g., `(u,v)` instead of `(x,y)`? This is actually easier for me, since my restrictions are given in terms of the Cartesian coordinates instead of the parameters. I tried `variable=\u`, `variable y=\v` and `restrict expr to domain={y+z}{0:100}`, but got the same error as above. Will it work if I install the unstable version from Sourceforge?

Comment: I try to clarify what I mean with "usability issue": `pgfplots` does not care about the variable names; and the efficiency will not change just by changing variable names. What I wanted to say is that end-users care about the names - and in your case, you have two variables `x` but their meaning is different: inside of the plot expression, it is the sampled variable and inside of the `restrict to domain` it is the *resulting* X coordinate. This disambiguity is confusing for any end-user (including me). That's what I call a usability issue: it is hard to use.

Comment: Concerning the original problem: the only cure is to get an updated version of pgfplots. At the time of this writing, the unstable available on `http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/` is your best choice (and: yes, it fixes the issue). The second-best choice is the git version. If you do not want to install these downloads, you have to wait for the next stable version.

Comment: It was indeed confusing for me too. With the unstable version installed, `variable=\u`, `variable y=\v` and `restrict expr to domain={y+z}{0:100}` now yield the expected result. Thank you!

Comment: Oops. Of course I should have written `y+z` instead of `x+y` - I misread your spec. Sorry